# Updating jQuery slick carousel on component update in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I just started with ReactJs and I can tell it's really awesome. But I came across an issue and I can't seem to figure out how to resolve this.

I'm trying to implement an automatic search filtering component that filters items based on their name. Here, I'm using movies and movie titles as an example. The search works, but as soon as I try to add some jQuery to the mix, I get this bug while trying to filter my search results:

**Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`**

Those nodes with the same `data-reactid` are the nodes created by the jQuery plugin, namely [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel.

Here you can try it yourself:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jDrzgzaERRM9HJ6Gsym?p=preview)

As soon as you comment **line 45** of `script.jsx`, you can see my search feature is working.

The thing is, the jQuery plugin is loaded in `componentDidMount`, as suggested in the [React docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), but when the DOM gets changed, everything is messed up, because the function is only called once. I need to reload the jQuery plugin when the data gets updated but I can't figure out exactly when, where and how.

I tried using `componentDidUpdate` instead, but it didn't work as expected. And it wouldn't get called on page load neither.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to do this:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  $(this.getDOMNode()).slick();
},
componentWillUpdate: function(){
  $(this.getDOMNode()).slick('unslick'); //remove the added dom elements
},
componentDidUpdate: function(){
  $(this.getDOMNode()).slick();
},
componentWillUnmount: function(){
  $(this.getDOMNode()).slick('unslick');
},
```

since even if react didn't throw an error this would be the easiest way to add/remove the elements to slick carousel. How feasible this is will depend on how many elements you plan on rendering and how performant slick carousel is.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon! I'll have about 300 elements, and around 9 or 12 per page, is that too many in your opinion?

Comment: The best way to know would be to just test it with a large dataset and see how it performs. If need be you could debounce the calls to filter so that you're not rerendering on every keystroke.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I Tested it with a large dataset (~1000 and 3 per page) and everything is so fast, even when filtering on every keystroke!