# React and jQuery slick carousel throws error

Tags: jquery, reactjs, carousel, slick.js

Inspired by this [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577304/updating-jquery-slick-carousel-on-component-update-in-reactjs) .

I applied the proposed solution to Plunker. Then I clicked an item, and the original bug appeared again.

> "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but
>   unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.1.4"

[Original Plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jDrzgzaERRM9HJ6Gsym?p=preview)

[My new plunker is here,](http://plnkr.co/edit/eLyLKIMJY3qybh4w2bSf?p=preview) with the changes I will annex to the bottom.

I was trying this out because I have a similar project with the same error message. I need to call a function on click. Here I just console.log a string, for simplicity. On first click the console.log is not called, but the *"Two valid but unequal..."* error is thrown. Only the second click will execute properly.

I think it all comes back to the question: **How to harmonize React with a jQuery plugin that creates copies of DOM nodes without adding keys to them as Reat expects.**

[I tried also this carousel](https://codepen.io/ygoex/pen/meeaGw), same error.

Changes I made to the Plunker:

ADDED LINES

```
componentWillUpdate: function(){
    $(this.getDOMNode()).slick('unslick'); //remove the added dom elements
},
componentDidUpdate: function(){
    $(this.getDOMNode()).slick();
},
componentWillUnmount: function(){
    $(this.getDOMNode()).slick('unslick');
},
```

CHANGED LINES

```
<MoviePage data={mp} key={i}/>  // added "key"

var movies = this.props.data.map(function(m, i){
    return (
        <Movie data={m} key={i}/>

return <div className="movie col-xs-4" onClick={function() {console.log("Some action")}}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carousels that duplicate the content should not be used with React, because it requires unique keys. That's my conclusion.

So the answer to myself is, I simply used the pure bootstrap carousel and organized 5 pictures in one slide. In the code sample, "image" is just a number, while I was testing this solution.

```
render: function() {
  var thumbs = [
    this.getRange(0, 4), // [0,1,2,3,4]
    this.getRange(5, 9),
    this.getRange(10, 12)
  ];

  return (
    <div className="carousel slide product-carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="0" id="productCarousel" data-wrap="false">
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        {thumbs.map(this.eachCarouselItem)}
      </div>
      <a className="left carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" data-slide="prev">P</a>
      <a className="right carousel-control" href="#productCarousel" data-slide="next">N</a>
    </div>
  )
},
eachCarouselItem: function(item, j) {
  return <div className={"item" + (j ? "" : " active")} key={j}>
    {item.map(this.eachCarouselImg)}
  </div>
},
eachCarouselImg: function(image, i) {
  return <div key={i}>
      <div className="img-responsive" onMouseOver={function (ev) {console.log("I am happy")}}>
        {image}
      </div>
  </div>
},
```